# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 5

Tags: java

What is wrong with my code (Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 5)........

```
public class AAExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AAExample nn = new AAExample();
        System.out.println(nn.isXOrZ("Pony"));
    }

    public  boolean isXOrZ(String text) {
    String  lower = text.toLowerCase();
    boolean found = false;
    int     i     = 0;

    while (!found) {
        String letter = lower.substring(i, i +1);

            if(letter.equals("z") || letter.equals("x"))
            found = true;

            i++;
        }

        return found;
    }
}
```

Comment: You keep incrementing `i` until you find either `z` or `x`, but `"Pony"` doesn't contain any of these. Now, what happens to `i`? And what happens to `letter`?

Answer (score 5):

Your while loop keep looping until `x` or `z` is found. Infinite loop occur when there is actually no `x` or `z` in your `String`.

`StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` occur when `i >= lower.length()-1`

So you need to modify your while loop to

```
 while (!found && i < lower.length()-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop terminating condition only relies on whether character is found or not.

```
while (!found)
```

Suppose, you don't found anything then you will never do

```
if(letter.equals("z") || letter.equals("x"))
   found=true
```

and keep on incrementing `i`, which will give you StringIndexOutOfBoundsException once it will be equals to string's length

Answer (score 0):

You are looping through the string until x or z is found. If x or z is not found, the loop will continue on past the end of the string.  This causes the exception.

I would recommend a for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < lower.length; i++) {
    String letter = lower.substring(i, i + 1);
    if(letter.equals("x") || letter.equals("z")) return true;
} 
return false;
```

Comment: You will still get `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` if there is no "x" or "z" (once you get this compile)